# How to construct a map from $\mathbb{ S}^2=\{(a_1,a_2,a_3) | a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2=1\}$ to $\mathbb{ RP}^2$?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology

How would I construct the map?
Once constucted, would I be right in saying that there is no Diffeomorphism to map back? As in $\mathbb{RP}^2$ a closed curve would have to have either $2$ points that represent the same $f(x)$ or one point that has $2$ values for $f(x)$? (It's not bijective)

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Easy: just map every point of $\Bbb{S}^2$ to the same point of $\Bbb{RP}^2$.

Comment: You are correct that the two are not diffeomorphic - one is orientable, and the other is not. It *may* be possible to find a smooth bijection $\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{RP}^2$ though, it just won't have a smooth inverse. I'm not sure if such a thing exists though.

Comment: @MattPressland: A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Ah, indeed. Very nice!

Comment: You can construct a map $f\colon S^2 \rightarrow RP^2$ easily. Just choose any point $p$ of $RP^2$ and define $f(x) = p$ for every $x \in S^2$. It is not only continuous, but also smooth. If you mean a bijective smooth map, there is no such thing because they are not homeomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

There is no global diffeomorphism from $S^2$ to $\mathbb{R}P^2$. This can be seen from the fact that their top de Rham cohomology groups are not isomorphic. Indeed, $H^2(S^2)=\mathbb{R}$ and $H^2(\mathbb{R}P^2)=0$.

As Chris Eagle pointed out, you cannot even have a continuous bijection between them, since their fundamental groups disagree. $\pi(S^2)=0$ while $\pi(\mathbb{R}P^2)=\mathbb{Z}_2$.

That said, there exists local diffeomorphisms between them. The "natural" map from $S^2$ to $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is the projection map $\pi$ with respect to the equivalence relation $x\sim -x \quad \forall x\in S^2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$, in the sense that $\pi$ is the [coequalizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coequalizer) of the identity and the antipodal map on $S^2$. This $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism.

Comment: I appreciate the responses. Makoto Kato, your map doesn't contain every point of the projective space in the image of f(x), would I be right in saying that a constant say c1*(a1,a2,a3) as because S^2 has magnitude 1 and RP is infinite in that sense?

Comment: @TheFanaticalMathematical Of course. But the question does not require a map to be surjective.